# Find a fundamental system for a topology induced by left continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, limits, continuity

> Let $I=(a,b)$ be an open interval of $\mathbb R$ and consider the space $X$ of functions $f:I\to \mathbb R$ which are left continuous at every point and have finite limit from the right.
>
> Given such an $f$, let $\bar f$ be defined on $J=I\times \{0,+\}$ by $$\bar f(x,0)=f(x)$$
> $$f(x,+)=\lim_{y\to x^+}f(y)$$
> Consider on $J$ the coarsest topology $\tau$ which makes all $\bar f$ continuous, when $f$ varies in $X$. Describe a fundamental neighbourhood system for every point of $J$ and prove that $(J,\tau)$ is $T_2$ and totally disconnected.

I tried to argue with the semiclosed-interval topology, but it doesn't seem to lead to anything. Notice also that if $f$ is continuous, then the Euclidean topology works, and furthermore, we can say that $\tau\supset \mathcal E$ (right?).

Thank you in advance for your help or for suggestion of tools/readings which explain fine arguments that can be useful in problems like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood left [right] continuity of the function $f$ at the point $x$ as the condition $\lim_{y\to x^-}f(y)=f(x)$
[$\lim_{y\to x^+}f(y)=f(x)$]. For each point $x\in I$ define a test function $t_x$ on the space $I$ by putting $t_x(y)=y-x$, if $y\le x$ and $t_x(y)=y-x+1$, if $y>x$. Then $\overline{t_x}(y,+)=y-x$, if $y< x$ and $\overline{t_x}(y,+)=y-x+1$, if $y\ge x$. The continuity of the function $\overline{t_x}$ at the point $(x,0)$ implies that the sets $(y,x]\times\{0\}$ ($a\le y<x$) are open in the space $(J,\tau)$.
The continuity of the function $\overline{t_x}$ at the point $(x,+)$ implies that the sets $[x,y]\times\{+\}$ ($x<y\le b$) are open in the space $(J,\tau)$. In fact, these sets form a base of the topology $\tau$. To see this it suffices to check that for each left continuous function $f:I\to\Bbb R$ the function $\hat f:I\to\Bbb R$ defined as $\hat f(x)=\lim_{y\to x^+}f(y)$ for each point $x\in I$ is right continuous. Fix arbitrary point $x\in I$ and a number $\varepsilon>0$. There exists a number $\delta>0$ such that 
$|f(y)-\hat f(x)|\le\varepsilon$ provided $x<y<x+\delta $. Therefore, $|\hat f(z)-\hat f(x)|=|\lim_{y\to z^+}f(y)-\hat f(x)|\le\varepsilon$ for each point $x<z<x+\delta$. Finally, it is obvious that $\tau$ is Hausdorff and totally disconnected.